# Adding profile data to database

Tags: sql, profiles

I added a custom field to my wordpress user profile page that asks a user what their favorite browser is. I have the field on the profile.php page, but how can I get this field into my sql database?

What sql script do I need that will insert the user's answer into the table by their corresponding user meta number?

Thanks

Comment: [A close look at user meta Qs might help you](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=update+user+meta&submit=search).

Answer (score 0):

To show extra fields in profile, use this hook:

```
function myplugin_show_profile_extra_fields( $user ) {
    // echo your extra fields here
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'myplugin_show_profile_extra_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'myplugin_show_profile_extra_fields' );
```

And to save extra fields use following hook:

```
function myplugin_save_profile_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'extra_field', $_POST['my_extra_field'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'myplugin_save_profile_extra_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'myplugin_save_profile_extra_fields' );
```